# The selected boot device failed Windows 10

Tags: boot, 14.04, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Windows 10. I was following [these steps](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/). My computer uses UEFI as BIOS mode as described [here](https://itsfoss.com/check-uefi-or-bios/). I have downloaded ISO image and created a live USB of Ubuntu. I have also allocated free space on my disk. Lastly I disabled secure boot and also enabled legacy support following these [steps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qnRWVhSVBE). Still, I get that my boot device have failed. What is wrong? I need to download Ubuntu for my work project please. I do not want it on Vmware or virtual box as I already had Ubuntu there and I think it is not that fast on a virtual machine. Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Boot into live Ubuntu and run command `sudo parted -l`. Post output into your question.

Comment: Somehow it worked now to boot from my usb device.